# Rails 4 hiding span in view

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I have a span that will display when an open house is detected in the db using `<% if listing.open_houses.exists? %>`. I need it to not be displayed when the date/time has passed. I have a controller method that does that for the open house itself, but not sure how to do it for the span in the view. I included the controller code below as a reference. Thanks for any help!

Controller Method:

```
@open_houses = OpenHouse.upcoming.where(listing_id: @listing.id).where('open_houses.start_date >= ?', Date.current).order(start_date: :asc)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use`<% if @open_houses.count >= 1 %>`! Something small and silly that took me way too much time to figure out.